# Is there a way to return a constexpr object based on the type of runtime values?

Tags: c++, templates, constexpr

Let's take a template class:

```
template<typename T>
class A{};
```

And a helper function that instantiates an A with type deduction:

```
template<typename T>
constexpr A<T> makeA(T)
{
    return A<T>();
}
```

And finally a runtime value, but whose type (`int`) is known at compile time:

```
int i = //... retrieving a runtime value;
```

The following does not compile, although it only uses the type of i, and not its value:

```
constexpr auto a = makeA(i);
```

The error being: the value of 'i' is not usable in a constant expression.

I understand that `i` can't be passed since its value is unknown at compile-time, but on the other hand `makeA` totally discards this value.

So how can I instantiate a constexpr A templated on the type of i, without having to spell out `A<int>` or `A<decltype(i)>`?

I'd imagine there must be a way since all the information is available at compile time.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: The question states this.

Comment: Why not makeA()?

Comment: You have also `decltype(makeA(i))`.

Comment: A constant expression must only contain (evaluated) constant sub-expressions. This is a simple rule that is easy to implement in a compiler. A (much) more complicated rule could in principle be defined, but this is deliberately not done (and `decltype` as a built-in language primitive is introduced specifically to extract types from non-constant expressions).  So the answer is no.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While all the information is available at compile-time, you're trying to really make it look like you're passing an object to the function at runtime. There is simply no way to do this other than the alternative methods you've already listed.

`makeA<int>()` seems perfectly reasonable to me (if remarkably contrived, but I'll assume your real `T` is more complex), and is consistent with "maker" functions already provided by the standard library.